# One site, multiple domains pointing to one CDN, search console questions

Tags: seo, search

My company currently has one main domain **abc.com** which is pointed to a CDN server using CNAME. However for our affiliates we have multiple domains that are pointed to the same CDN server using CNAME as well for example-

**abc1.com**
**abc2.com**

My question is how do I make google deindex my affiliate's domains on google as they are appearing above my main domain **abc.com** in search results. Do I create a property for each affiliate domain in Google Search Console and submit robot file to deindex?